# HTML::Entities::encode_entities_numeric: Convert hex output to decimal

Tags: perl, html-entities

I am using [HTML::Entities](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTML::Entities) module to encode some special chars. Here is my sample code:

```
use HTML::Entities qw(encode_entities_numeric);
my $str = "some special chars like € ™ © ®";
encode_entities_numeric($str);
print $str;

Output: &#x20AC; &#x2122; &#xA9; &#xAE;
```

As output is in HTML numeric hex code of the char.

I want output in form of HTML numeric decimal value of the chars like  `&#8364; &#8482; &#169; &#174;`
Is there a way to do this in `encode_entities_numeric()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HTML::Entities does the conversion in a little sub named `num_entry`. Redefine that to be whatever you want:

```
use utf8;
use HTML::Entities qw(encode_entities_numeric);

{
no warnings 'redefine';
sub HTML::Entities::num_entity { sprintf "&#%d;", ord($_[0]); }
}

my $str = "some special chars like € ™ © ®";
encode_entities_numeric($str);
print $str;
```

For what it's worth, this is the sort of thing Perl wants you to do. It's designed so that you can change things in this manner. It would be nicer if HTML::Entities were set up to allow derived classes, but it's not. Perl, recognizing that the world is messy like this, has ways for you to adjust that for what you need.

Comment: Ah, excellent! On behalf of those of us with a requirement for this behavior - often not of our own making, but rather thrust upon us involuntarily as a constraint ... thank you!

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not configurable (because `&#x20AC;` and `&#8364;` are 100% equivalent in HTML).